# Are there examples of 1-forms on R2: Φ = $f_1$dx + $f_2$dy, such Φ that is not the differential of a function f

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to figure out differentials and 1-forms and have stumbled upon the following question: Are there examples of 1-forms on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$: Φ = $f_1$dx + $f_2$dy, such Φ that is not the differential of a function $f$.  I am currently trying to understand how 1 forms and differentials can even be different and think it may have something to do if the vector is conservative or not?  I am unsure how to proceed and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pick any non-conservative form you like. For example, consider $x dy$.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean and that probably starts with my lack of understanding in this topic.  I know how to calculate differentials, but given some non conservative vector, I'm not so sure how I would go about calculating its 1-form.

Comment: The important thing to note here is that $d^2 \omega = 0$ for all $\omega$. So pick some $\Phi$ such that $d\Phi \neq 0$. Then $\Phi$ is not of the form $d\omega$ for any $\omega$. In this case, we pick $xdy$, whose derivative is $dx dy$.

Comment: Let me elaborate on @MarkSaving's answer. Try to find a function $f$ whose differential is $x\,dy$. In other words, try to find a function $f$ such that $df = x\,dy$. If you do this, you'll find that there is no solution. This means that $x\,dy$ is not the differential of a function.